# Identify this plant please (western Europe)

Tags: identification

[image: photo1]
[image: photo2]

This plant has started to grow in my garden (in Northern France) last fall. I decided to let it live its life, and although I have neither protected nor watered nor taken care of it in any way, it has passed the winter and thrived.

Right now it is about one meter high.

More photos : [photo2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-ClDtD8VnUmrTK24GsjTh_gBxwulSuhN/view?usp=drivesdk);[photo1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-CS0bl7_xgqevGIoQ3uzxC90d1YV9ykG/view?usp=drivesdk);[photo3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-6lvalTDn3WV-cqo0KElMJN2wZIjKB-_/view?usp=drivesdk);[photo4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-1cDaJoSCXdwnjWvRihTsgG_2H407sku/view?usp=drivesdk)

What species is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like mullien - Verbascum thapas - found in the US.

Comment: Do NOT let it go to seed, unless you want hundreds more just like it.

Comment: ... or another Verbascum. The asker is in Europe, where V tapiscum is a neophyte. We may have to wait until the plant flowers.

Comment: Yeah. There are many wild Verbascum in Europe.  Verbascum thapsus is a good guess (note: real name is thap**sus**, always latin-like suffixes)